# Is there a way of accessing the methods variables without calling the method?

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

I want to make a simple GUI that will allow user to pick an excel file to load the data from that will later be used for math calculations. Both modules work correctly when separate. But when I try to use my GUI as an import into my main file I am unable to access the needed var without calling the class method which in turn iterates it. It is troublesome because it is supposed to use this function only after the button press.

Is there something fundamentally wrong that I am doing?

GUI script

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as tkf

class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.dialogButton = tk.Button(frame, text="choose", command=self.chooseFile)
        self.dialogButton.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

    def chooseFile(self):
        global filename
        filename = tkf.askopenfilename()
        print(filename)
```

Import script

```py
import tkinterTest as tt
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

classObject = tt.TestClass(root)
var = classObject.chooseFile()
print(var)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to access the path string only with the GUI so that it gives me the string only after I press the button to select the file not right after the program starts.

Comment: Delete the two lines `var = ...` and `print(var)`.  These run before you call `root.mainloop` which is before the GUI appears.  If you set filename as an attribute of TestClass you can access it later as classObject.filename.

Comment: Thank you, it help. I did not use class attribute but class variable but this time correctly called it. Anyway, I have a lot of learning about classes still. Thanks again!